# Getting number of random timestamps throughout a day in Java

Tags: java, random, timestamp

What would be a good way to go about this? I wish to show a message 5 times at random times throughout a day. I currently use the following method to generate timestamps:

```
List<Long> timestamps = new ArrayList<Long>();

long currentTimestamp = (long) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);
long endTimestamp = addHoursToTimestamp(8, currentTimestamp);

int n_timestamps = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < n_timestamps; i++) {
    Long randomTime = currentTimestamp + Math.abs(new Random().nextLong()) % (endTimestamp-currentTimestamp);
    timestamps.add(randomTime);
}
```

Sometimes this works good and I get nicely spread out timestamps. Of course as you can imagine, sometimes the timestamps are really close to one another, like in this example where there are 3 timestamps at the 11th hour (in a timespan of 11:00-19:00):

```
1435483835  Sun Jun 28 11:30:35 CEST 2015
1435501808  Sun Jun 28 16:30:08 CEST 2015
1435484646  Sun Jun 28 11:44:06 CEST 2015
1435495886  Sun Jun 28 14:51:26 CEST 2015
1435483799  Sun Jun 28 11:29:59 CEST 2015
```

This is not ideal, since I want the timestamps to be spread out a bit. To fix this I created a function that loops over all timestamps already added to the array, and check if the generated timestamp is at least an hour later or earlier than each of those.

However, I don't know if this is the preferred way to go about it. Seems pretty heavy in computation.

Comment: `[-----(--|--)-----(--|--)-----(--|--)-----(--|--)-----(--|--)-----]` This means that you might define an average distance `|-----------|` - perhaps one sixth of the day - and randomize by adding/subtracting a short delta `(--|--)`.

Comment: Why do you want it random and yet when it is random you are not happy with it?

Comment: @redge Events etc. may happen according to a certain distribution which isn't necessarily uniform.

Comment: Events are one thing and an event driven approach can be used but the question is about random timestamps but randomness has been rejected by the questioner.  I am trying to understand what the real requirement is so that an appropriate answer can be provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would generate a random time for each evenly spaced time period like this:

```
List<Long> timestamps = new ArrayList<Long>();
long currentTimestamp = (long) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);

int hourRange = 8;    
int n_timestamps = 5;
double timePeriod = hourRange / (n_timestamps + 0.0);
Random rand = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < n_timestamps; i++) {
    long startTimestamp = addHoursToTimestamp(i, currentTimestamp);
    long endTimestamp = addHoursToTimestamp(timePeriod, startTimestamp);

    Long randomTime = startTimestamp + Math.abs(rand.nextLong()) % (endTimestamp-startTimestamp);
    timestamps.add(randomTime);
}
```

So for an 8 hour period, a random time will be generated for each of the 5 periods of 1h36m.

Just make sure `addHoursToTimeStamp()` can accept a `double` value.